# List items in object list once ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, object, create-react-app

I have this file:

#### ProductList.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function ProductList() {

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    var listeditems = {};
    const list = document.getElementById("list");
    if (items !== null) {
        for (let f = 0; f < Object.keys(items).length; f++) {
            const item = items[f];
            
            if (!Object.keys(items).includes(item.name)) {
                listeditems[item.name] = null;
                list.innerHTML +=
                  "<p>" + item.name + ", sells for €" + item.price + "</p>";
            }
        }
    } else {
      list.innerText = "None yet!";
    }
});

return (
    <span id="list"></span>
);
}
```

Which is rendered in App.js like so:

```
import ProductList from './ProductList';

return(
    // Something
    <ProductList/>
    // And more...
);
```

Where `items` is `{"0":{"name":"Banana","price":"0.22"}}`. this outputs this:

> `<span id="list"><p>Banana, sells for €0.22</p><p>Banana, sells for €0.22</p></span>`

As you see, the `<p>Banana, sells for €0.22</p>` is twice in there whilst it is only once in the object(list).

**How do I prevent this?**, how do I only get one `<p>...</p>` per item in the list.

Comment: Unrelated, but this seems an incredibly non-React way to do what you're trying to do. Why is it like this?

Comment: +1 to Dave , instead, use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) and [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate). Also, if you want to do it put your code `useEffect(() => {/* here */}, [])` See the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var out;

    if (items !== null) {
        for (let f = 0; f < Object.keys(items).length; f++) {
            const item = items[f];
            if(item.name !== undefined){
                out += "<li>" + item.name + ", sells for €" + item.price + "</li>";
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            document.getElementById("list").innerHTML= out.replace("undefined", "");
        });
    } else {
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            document.getElementById("list").innerHTML="<li>None yet</li>";
        });
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>A list of your products</h3>
            <ul id="list"></ul>
        </div>
    );
```